# implementing another class to create the first 100 prime numbers

Tags: java, validation, testing, primes, implementation

ok I'm a little mind blown from an assignment i have to do. We have to implement a sequence class from **wiley.com/go/javaexamples** (the chapter 10 example) to make a new class called PrimeSequence and it has to right align the first 100 prime sequence numbers. I don't understand the point of implementing the other class and i did it but i know im not following the assignment rules because i dont understand what im supposed to implement from the other class and i also use nothing from the other class. I'm not sure on what i have to do

Sequence Class

```
public interface Sequence 
{   
    int next();
}
```

PrimeSequence Class

```
public class PrimeSequence implements Sequence
{

public PrimeSequence()
{

}

public boolean isPrime(int x)
{
    for (int start = 2; start <= Math.sqrt(x); start++)
    {
        if (x % start == 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    public int next()
    {

    }
}
```

PrimeSequenceTester

```
public class PrimeSequenceTester {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    PrimeSequence prime = new PrimeSequence();

    int currentNumber = 2;
    int primesFound = 0;

    while (primesFound < 100) {
        if (prime.isPrime(currentNumber)) 
        {
            primesFound++;

            System.out.printf("%4s",currentNumber + " ");
            if (primesFound % 10 == 0) 
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        currentNumber++;
}
}
```

Comment: learn what an interface is for.

Comment: i get that the implementation lets you use abstract methods but I don't know how to apply that here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation using a Sieve of Eratosthenes (sieving only the odd numbers) and optimised to only sieve numbers once across multiple instances of the sequence. You need to do something a **LOT** simpler and just keep a track of what the current prime is and override the `next()` function so that when it is called you keep incrementing the value of the current prime until your `isPrime()` function returns true and then return that value.

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class PrimeSequence implements Sequence {
    private static final BitSet OddPrimeSieve = new BitSet( 8000 );
    private static int MaxSievedPrime = 2;

    static {
        OddPrimeSieve.set(0, OddPrimeSieve.size() - 1, true );
    }

    private static int PrimeToIndex( final int prime ){
        return (prime - 3) / 2;
    }

    private static int IndexToPrime( final int index ){
        return 2*index + 3;
    }

    private static synchronized void setMaxSievedPrime( final int max ){
        MaxSievedPrime = max;
        for ( int index = PrimeToIndex( MaxSievedPrime ) + MaxSievedPrime;
                index < OddPrimeSieve.length();
                index += MaxSievedPrime )
            OddPrimeSieve.set( index, false );
    }

    int currentPrime = 2;

    @Override
    public synchronized int next() {
        final int current = currentPrime;
        if ( current == 2 )
        {
            currentPrime++;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( currentPrime > MaxSievedPrime )
                setMaxSievedPrime( currentPrime );
            currentPrime = IndexToPrime( OddPrimeSieve.nextSetBit( PrimeToIndex( currentPrime ) + 1 ) );
        }
        return current;
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        PrimeSequence p = new PrimeSequence();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            System.out.println( p.next() );
    }
}
```